# Sails, EJS data is not defined in forEach loop

Tags: mongodb, express, sails.js, ejs, sails-mongo

I am working on Sails.js CRUD application (article management) with MongoDB based on @bradtraversy tutorial. I have encountered issue while trying to display articles from the database using EJS syntax and forEach loop. Error says "articles data is not defined".
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dge6I.png)

Basically I pass examplary record to Mongo via Sails `/Create?title=ArticleOne%20body=BodyOne` URL blueprint. The article can be clearly seen in Mongo. [MongoDB article image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoD8e.png)

datastores.js is configured for Mongo:

```
 module.exports.datastores = {

 mongodb: {

    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    database: 'articlebase'
  },

};
```

routes.js points out list.ejs view:

```
 module.exports.routes = {

  '/': { view: 'pages/homepage' },
  '/articles/list': { view: 'pages/list' },
  '/articles/add': { view: 'pages/add' },

};
```

Article.js model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
     title:{
       type: 'string'
     },
     body:{
      type: 'string'
    }
  },
  datastore: 'mongodb'

};
```

ArticlesController.js

```
module.exports = {

    list:function(req, res){
        Articles.find({}).exec(function(err, articles){
            if(err){
                res.send(500, {error: 'Database Error'});
            }
            res.view('list', {articles:articles});

        });
    },

    add: function(req, res){
        res.view('add');
    }

};
```

And finally troublesome list.ejs view:

```
<h1 class="display-4">Articles</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% articles.forEach(function(article){ %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= article.id %></td>
                <td><%= article.title %></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/articles/edit/<%= article.id %>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                    <form class="d-inline" action="/articles/delete/<%= article.id %>" method="post">
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

How can I display articles from MongoDB "articles" collection with EJS correctly? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your controller method is encountering an error, but you are not returning when you get the error. My first guess would be *Article* vs *Articles* but I could be wrong. Change to this to help you see what's up:

```
list:function(req, res){
    Articles.find({}).exec(function(err, articles){
        if(err){
            sails.log('Error summary: ' + err);
            sails.log(err);
            return res.send(500, {error: 'Database Error'}); // note the return!
        }
        res.view('list', {articles:articles});
    });
},
```

Otherwise, nice work on the error tracking!

Answer (score 0):

So I was getting this error repeatedly, and my fix was to check the definition of "articles".
If your ejs file is accessing the model "articles" after updating the model using jquery functions, then when you render the ejs file, you can pass the updated "articles" model as a parameter.
Like,

```
    const articles = await Article.find().sort('-entryTime');
    res.render('route/ejsfilename', { articles:articles });
```

This part of the code can be specified in your controller or app.js file(wherever you render your ejs).
In that way when you render the ejs file, you won't get an error of "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" or "articles data is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

go to config/blueprints.js, set
actions: true

blueprints will do auto route for you.